# Visual Studio option to turn a written code block into a method?

Tags: visual-studio

A while ago I was watching a video where the presenter cleaned up his code by highlighting already written code, and choosing some option that converted the code into a method. It also automatically recognized what parameters needed to be passed, and all he needed to do was name the method.

Does anyone know what this option is called? I have looked all over and cannot find it. I can't remember the video either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was probably refactoring. Highlight your code, right click and select "Quick Actions and Refactorings", then select "Extract Method". (Or choose Edit Menu > Refactor > Extract Method.)

You'll be able to change the name of the new method. Visual Studio does its best to figure out what types are needed as parameters, what should be returned, what visibility for the method is needed, etc. You'll still want to double check the result and make sure it does what you want.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. When you don't know the term, it can be hard to find the answer.

Comment: It is a super useful function. I use it all the time.

Comment: Also Ctrl-. is usually the quick way to show that menu.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's called refactoring your code. You can extract a method by right clicking on the highlighted method and choosing Extract Method from context menu. VS will extract the method and set the parameters for you.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!